# Send a unique link using Enhanced SMS

Tags: sms, survey, salesforce-survey, digital-engagement

We're trying to send a url with in an SMS which is unique to each recipient. However, the current Enhanced SMS feature only supports plain text. There is an option to send an sms with a Enhanced link messaging component, however it will be a static link something like [www.company.com](http://www.company.com) etc.

I have tried raising multiple tickets with salesforce to see if there is any workaround as sms with links seems to be a basic offering by many other competitors. So trying to check with the experts here desperate to see if there is any workaround something like, show a static link & then clicking that will open another page/link with unique id example: [www.company.com/{SurveyId}&{SurveyInvitationId}&{UUID}](http://www.company.com/%7BSurveyId%7D&%7BSurveyInvitationId%7D&%7BUUID%7D) etc which will be specific to the recipient.

Please let me know. Thanks!